# MIPS Cross Compiler Invalid instruction

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, inline-assembly

I would like to generate MIPS binaries using gcc in Centos7. I've successfully install binutils and gcc.

Command line I used for cross-compilation:

```
mips-mti-elf-gcc -o exception.o exception.c
```

Then the error that show up is like:

`/tmp/ccFbK9Ow.s: Assembler messages:
 /tmp/ccFbK9Ow.s:123: Error: invalid operands addiu $8,$sp,'`

And this is the problem line

```
  /* exception function arguments */
    "   srl $4, $9, 2           \n" /* adjust cause arg */
    "   move    $5, $8              \n" /* execution pointer */
    "   mfc0    $6, $8              \n" /* bad address if any */
    "   addiu   $7, $sp,    0           \n" /* register table on stack */
    "   addiu   $8, $sp,                \n" /* stack pointer */
    "   sw  $8, 4*4($sp)            \n"
    "   la      $1, interrupt_ex_handler    \n"
    "   jalr    $1                  \n"
    "   j   return                  \n"
```

Where am i missing?

Comment: The `addiu   $8, $sp,` is missing immediate (like the one above has `0`). Looks like gcc bug, can you edit your question and add also `exception.c` source and `...gcc --version`?

Comment: That looks more like broken inline asm to me.

Comment: @Jester sure, the quotes and `\n` are obvious, now you mentioned it, but without the `.c` file I was refusing to think about it too much, as it could have been anything. And it looks to me you are right. So this question can be rephrased as: "I wrote invalid instruction and compiler is reporting invalid instruction and I wonder why"... well, that's how it works.  .... actually that's the inlined assembly itself, part of C file, right? I somehow expected content of .s file in the question, but in the end the OP did a right thing, posting .c source of the problem, I just misunderstood it.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly is invalid.  The line;

```
addiu   $7, $sp,    0
```

looks ok.

```
addiu   $8, $sp,
```

is missing the final operand after the comma.  I'd guess it should be;

```
addiu   $8, $sp,     0
```

It's not clear from your questions whether the assembly in question is embedded in the C file, or if it is being generated by the compiler - I'm assuming the former.  If not, it would probably help to post a minimal example C file which shows the issue.